# Printing a tree structure in a list like manner, storing the indent strings (which consist of┣, ┃, ┗ )

Tags: javascript, tree

I want to store the "node indentation string" for each object, something like this:

```
foo
┣bar
┃┗baz
┃ ┗qux
┃  ┣quux
┃  ┗corge
┣fizz
┗buzz
```

Given data for each object:

```
objects = [
{'id':1,'parent_id':null, 'name':'foo'}
{'id':2,'parent_id':1, 'name':'bar'}
];
```

Note that I don't want to print anything, I just want to work out the `indent` as an array of characters for each object:

`{'id':6,'parent_id':4, 'name':'corge', 'indent':['┃',' ',' ','┗']}`

So far I can only indent them with spaces but no 'pipes' and I am stumped at coming up with a solution. Any help?

I am using JS with Angular if it helps.

EDIT: As requested the code I have so far. I didn't post this at first because I felt that it's a wrong foundation/approach to build on. How it works is pretty trivial: for each object, count it's ancestors and add `" "`'s accordingly.

```
// go through all our objects and set their indent strings
setIndents = function()
{
    for (var x in objects) {
        var o = objects[x];
        o.nodes = [];

        // push space character for amount of ancestors
        numParents = countParents(o, 0);
        for (var i = 0; i < numParents; i++)
            o.nodes.push(" ");
    }
};
// recursively counts how many ancestors until we hit the root
countParents = function(current, count)
{
    if (current.parent_id !== null) {
        for (var x in objects) {
            if (objects[x].id == current.parent_id) {
                current = objects[x]; //set as new current
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }
        return countParents(current, count);
    } else {
        return count;
    }

};
```

Comment: Would you also add your existing code that creates the indents? This will allow for suggestions on how to improve it

Comment: @IvayloSlavov yes, absolutely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @JBCP pointed out (see comments) there is a serious flaw in my original code that would break the whole thing if the initial order was anything but perfect.

So here's an updated version, the order of elements can now be random (it still plays a role in such that it indirectly defines the children order, but the tree-structure will be correct).

I also split the functions so that they can be better configured. For example `treeIndent` now expects a *node branch* produced by `treeify`. (Note: the `shuffle` function is just there to test the *order independence*)

```js
'use strict';

/**
 * @see https://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/
 *
 * @param array
 * @returns {*}
 */
function shuffle(array) {
    var m = array.length, t, i;

    // While there remain elements to shuffle…
    while (m) {
        // Pick a remaining element…
        i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

        // And swap it with the current element.
        t = array[m];
        array[m] = array[i];
        array[i] = t;
    }

    return array;
}

function treeify(flat) {
    var map = { __root__: { children: [] }};

    flat.forEach(function (node) {
        var
            parentId = node.parent_id || '__root__',
            id = node.id;

        // init parent
        if (!map.hasOwnProperty(parentId)) {
            map[parentId] = { element: null, children: [] };
        }

        // init self
        if (!map.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
            map[id] = { element: null, children: [] };
        }

        map[id].element = node;
        map[parentId].children.push(map[id]);
    });

    return map.__root__.children;
}

function treeIndent(branch, cfg, decorator, indent)
{
    indent = indent || [];

    branch.forEach(function (node, i) {
        decorator(node.element, indent.concat(
            i === branch.length - 1 ? cfg.isLastChild : cfg.hasNextSibling
        ));

        treeIndent(node.children, cfg, decorator, indent.concat(
            i === branch.length - 1 ? cfg.ancestorIsLastChild : cfg.ancestorHasNextSibling
        ));
    });
}

var input = [
    { id: 1, parent_id: null,              name: 'root'  },
        { id: 2, parent_id: 1,             name: 'bar'   },
            { id: 5, parent_id: 2,         name: 'baz'   },
                { id: 6, parent_id: 5,     name: 'qux'   },
                    { id: 7, parent_id: 6, name: 'quux'  },
                    { id: 8, parent_id: 6, name: 'corge' },
            { id: 9, parent_id: 2,         name: 'but'   },
        { id: 3, parent_id: 1,             name: 'fizz'  },
        { id: 4, parent_id: 1,             name: 'buzz'  }
];

var log = document.getElementById('log');

treeIndent(treeify(shuffle(input)), {
    hasNextSibling:         '&boxvr;',
    isLastChild:            '&boxur;',
    ancestorHasNextSibling: '&boxv;',
    ancestorIsLastChild:    ' '
}, function (element, indent) {
    log.innerHTML += indent.join(' ') + ' ' + element.name + "\n";
});
```

```html
<pre id="log"></pre>
```

---

**Old answer (broken!)**:

try the following:

```
function makeTree(flat) {
  var map = { __root__: { children: [] }};

  flat.forEach(function (node) {
    var
      parentId = node.parent_id || '__root__',
      id = node.id;

    // init parent
    if (!map.hasOwnProperty(parentId)) {
      map[parentId] = { children: [] };
    }

    // init self
    if (!map.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
      map[id] = { children: [] };
    }

    map[id].element = node;
    map[parentId].children.push(map[id]);
  });

  return map.__root__.children;
}

function injectTreeIndent(input) {
  var
    levelMap = [],
    indicators = {
      hasNextSibling:         '┣',
      isLastChild:            '┗',
      ancestorHasNextSibling: '┃',
      ancestorIsLastChild:    ' '
    }
  ;

  // apply `indent`
  (function traverse(branch, depth) {
    branch.forEach(function (node, idx) {
      node.element.indent = levelMap.map(function (ancestor) {
        return ancestor === indicators.hasNextSibling ? indicators.ancestorHasNextSibling : indicators.ancestorIsLastChild;
      });

      // if (depth > 0) { // uncomment this, if root elements should have no indentation
      node.element.indent.push(
        levelMap[depth] = branch.length - 1 > idx ? indicators.hasNextSibling : indicators.isLastChild
      );
      // }

      traverse(node.children, depth + 1);

      levelMap.pop();
    });
  }(makeTree(input), 0));
}

var input = [
  { id: 1, parent_id: null, name: 'foo'   },
  { id: 2, parent_id: 1,    name: 'bar'   },
  { id: 5, parent_id: 2,    name: 'baz'   },
  { id: 6, parent_id: 5,    name: 'qux'   },
  { id: 7, parent_id: 6,    name: 'quux'  },
  { id: 8, parent_id: 6,    name: 'corge' },
  { id: 3, parent_id: 1,    name: 'fizz'  },
  { id: 4, parent_id: 1,    name: 'buzz'  }
];

injectTreeIndent(input);
```

- `makeTree` is used to optain a nested structure derived from the given flat data.
- `injectTreeIndent` then traverses that nested structure to inject the required indent informatoin.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6R7wf/1/

demo with root elements having no indenation: http://jsfiddle.net/zMY7v/

Comment: This looks pretty neat and efficient. However I think root elements will end up having something like `┗foo` (which should be `foo`) and the rest will be indented by an extra space. I ran into this problem too, if you can update your solution to satisfy this it would be great!

Comment: @tiffanyhwang that's not that much of a problem, just add a condition requiring the current depth to be > 0 (which will fail for root elements). See the comment in the code, and the second demo.

Comment: this solution seems to have some bugs with handling the order of the input nodes. At least with the jsfiddle demo, if you add sibling nodes you will get bad results. See the 'broken1' and 'broken2' nodes in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b6gxcakt/ It seems to be related to not respecting the parent_id field, although I haven't read through the code.

Comment: @JBCP you're right, seems that old code is dependent on the correct order of elements. I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1):

After `for (var i = 0; i < numParents; i++) o.nodes.push(" ");`, try

```
if (o.nodes.length === 1)
    o.nodes[0] = "┣";
else if (o.nodes.length > 1) {
    o.nodes[0] = "┃";
    o.nodes[o.nodes.length - 1] = "┗";
}
```

Comment: `o.nodes[0] = "┃";` will not produce the correct result e.g. http://pastebin.com/zqSYJmGu, I'll try playing and adding more logic to your solution and see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const addIndents = objects => {
  objects.forEach(o => o.children = objects.filter(o2 => o2.parent_id === o.id));
  const roots = objects.filter(o => !objects.some(o2 => o2.children.includes(o)));
  roots.forEach(o => addTree(o));
};

const PFXs = { true: { true: " ", false: "┃" }, false: { true: "┗", false: "┣" }};
const addTree = (t, levels = []) => {
  t.indent = levels.map((p, i) => PFXs[i < levels.length - 1][p]);
  t.children?.forEach((x, i) => addTree(x, [...levels, i === t.children.length-1]));
};

const objects = [
  {id: 1, parent_id: null, name: "foo"},
  {id: 2, parent_id: 1, name: "bar"},
  {id: 3, parent_id: 2, name: "baz"},
  {id: 4, parent_id: 3, name: "qux"},
  {id: 5, parent_id: 4, name: "quux"},
  {id: 6, parent_id: 4, name: "corge"},
  {id: 7, parent_id: 1, name: "fizz"},
  {id: 8, parent_id: 1, name: "buzz"},
];

addIndents(objects);

objects.forEach(o => console.log(o.indent.join("") + o.name))
```