# traverses a tree data structure and prints the contents in the specified format - javascript, typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, data-structures

recently I have one task that says: traverses a tree data structure and print the content in the specified format I have tried till now but I can't achieve what I want.

```
const data = {
  name: "my-project",
  children: [
 {
  name: "node_modules",
  children: [
    {
      name: "react",
      children: [
        { name: "docs", children: [] },
       
      ],
    },
  ],
},
{ name: "src", children: [{ name: "index.js" }] },
]};


// my-project
// ├── node_modules
// │   └── react
// │       ├── docs
// └── src
//     └── index.js
```

I am trying to solve like this but any help would be good.

```
let position = 0;

function start(tree) {
if (!tree) {
 return
}
let current = tree;

if(position === 0) {
 console.log('// ' + current.name);
} else {
 console.log(`// ${'     '.repeat(position)}|___${current.name}`);
}

while(current) {
 current = current.children.shift();
 position++;
 start(current);
}
}

start(data);
```

Comment: It would be very helpful to see how you're building the tree and the output from what you have already written. Otherwise, we can only guess what might be wrong.

Comment: I don't have any function that builds the tree this is just a task from professor and the tree is given by his mind just for testing.

Comment: look at this https://gist.github.com/danielstocks/5da83982d3b4c7b503a0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing a tree structure in a list like manner, storing the indent strings (which consist of┣, ┃, ┗ )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22038162/printing-a-tree-structure-in-a-list-like-manner-storing-the-indent-strings-whi)

Answer (score 1):

How's this?

```
const data = {
  name: "my-project",
  children: [
 {
  name: "node_modules",
  children: [
    {
      name: "react",
      children: [
        { name: "docs", children: [] },
       
      ],
    },
  ],
},
{ name: "src", children: [{ name: "index.js" }] },
]};

const prettyPrint = (tree, depth) => {
    if(depth === 0) {
   console.log('// ' + tree.name);
  } else if (depth === 1) {
   console.log(`// |${'────'.repeat(depth)} ${tree.name}`);
  } else {
   console.log(`// |${'    '.repeat(depth - 1)} |──── ${tree.name}`);
  }
  
  if(tree.children){
    tree.children.forEach(curr => prettyPrint(curr, depth + 1));
  }
}

prettyPrint(data, 0)
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7qoyg8ep/

Comment: it has also a problem I can't print the last object { name: "src", children: [{ name: "index.js" }] }

Comment: @spyrox I see, the original graph traversal was incorrect, I've fixed the code and the fiddle (I believe)

Comment: it works somehow but check this link https://jsfiddle.net/8x6fqgjw/1/ and also check output how should it be

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = {
  name: "my-project",
  children: [
    { name: "node_modules", children: [{ name: "react", children: [{ name: "docs", children: [] }]}]},
    { name: "src", children: [{ name: "index.js" }] },
  ]
};

const PFXs = { true: { true: "     ", false: "┃    " }, false: { true: "┗━━━ ", false: "┣━━━ " } };
const printTree = (t, levels = []) => {
  const pfx = (p, i) => PFXs[i < levels.length - 1][p];
  console.log(`${levels.map(pfx).join("")}${t.name}`);
  t.children?.forEach((x, i) => printTree(x, [...levels, i === t.children.length-1]));
};
printTree(data);
```